# Nonclustered Columnstore Index Disk Space (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, columnstore

Does a nonclustered columnstore index take additional disk space? I realize that a traditional nonclustered index would. However, I thought with columnstore indexes (including NC) would store the underlying table data to do the column compression.

If it does store the NC Columnstore Index separately, is it essentially making a copy of the table with those specific columns included in the index?

Thanks in advance for any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, nonclustered columnstore index requires extra space as nonclustered index is a secondary index created on a rowstore table.

The nonclustered index contains a copy of part or all of the rows and columns in the underlying table, so it needs additional space.